# Sliding in uitextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am having text which is more than the width of the `UITextField`. The text is getting truncated and dots are added at the end of the text. How can I achieve the functionality of `EditText` (in Android) where we can slide through the textfield if the text in the textfield is more than the width, without decreasing the font size.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.Can u give me the solution if you have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

If your textfield is not editable then it will be good to use UILabel inside UIScrollView.

1. set the width of label equals to text size keeping height constant.
2. set the content size of scrollview equals to label's size.

Hope this will work.

If you need code example, I can provide.

Comment: It is not editable,but the value in the textfield Keeps changing.

Comment: MargueeLabel will however scroll the text automatically for a defined animation duration. There is no user interaction.

Comment: you can enable user interaction for UILabel.